# Prisma client generated type for create input has weird type requirement for related table field, how to get a working type?

Tags: node.js, nestjs, prisma, nestjs-graphql

Use case is simple:

- users table
- sessions table

Each user can be logged in multiple places therefore they can have multiple sessions -> one to many relationship. in SQL this isn't a big deal/problem, but the generated types available in `@prisma/client` create a weird type when it comes to the input models.

I'm using NestJS and need TS models based on classes that exist at runtime, so I can make use of decorators on keys for input validation and graphql usage.

I'm creating a model based off of the `Prisma.SessionCreateInput` coming from `@prisma/client`.

prisma schema:

```
model User {
  id                   String    @id @default(uuid())
...
  sessions             Session[]
}

model Session {
  id        String    @id @default(uuid())
  user      User      @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  userId    String
}
```

The TS model:

```
import { Prisma } from '@prisma/client';

export class SessionModel implements Prisma.SessionCreateInput {
  id?: string;
  userId?: string;
  user: Prisma.UserCreateNestedOneWithoutSessionsInput;
}
```

Now I'm defining the type for user explicitly based on what Prisma is telling me to, in my opinion I don't need any user data there when creating a session, merely the userId.

`UserCreateNestedOneWithoutSessionsInput`:

```
type Prisma.UserCreateNestedOneWithoutSessionsInput = {
    create?: (Prisma.Without<Prisma.UserCreateWithoutSessionsInput, Prisma.UserUncheckedCreateWithoutSessionsInput> & Prisma.UserUncheckedCreateWithoutSessionsInput) | (Prisma.Without<...> & Prisma.UserCreateWithoutSessionsInput);
    connectOrCreate?: Prisma.UserCreateOrConnectWithoutSessionsInput;
    connect?: Prisma.UserWhereUniqueInput;
}
```

which seems some sort of meta type that I very much do not need?

**How can I maintain type safety and have these derived TS classes to work with?**

Comment: Prisma creates 2 types for creating, there is also an uncheckedCreateInput, that will only have userId. Try extending SessionUncheckedCreateInput

Comment: Thank you, I'll give that a try. 

Do you know of any documentation differentiating for use cases between the two types?

Comment: I don't know, only prisma doc I know is this https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/crud#create but I think it is not explained there

Comment: So this works for resolving the input purposes, but then when I define the UserModel with its session: SessionModel[] -- I can't apply the model I created that contains the typescript decorators for GQL, it expects some weird meta types similarly to the initial issue.

Comment: Did you had a look at this guide for advanced type safety with Prisma to create a custom type for getting users with session: https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/advanced-type-safety/operating-against-partial-structures-of-model-types#problem-using-variations-of-the-generated-model-type

Comment: I did not! that looks like an excellent guide, thank you.